# How do I record time spent on each screen in react native expo?

Tags: react-native, timer, expo, analytics

I am working on a project, and we need to record analytics concerning how long a user spends on each page. We have looked into Firebase analytics, but since we are using Expo, it is not fulfilling our requirements. How would I set a timer on each page so that I can record the time spent on each page? We have navigation set up like this:

```
    navigation.navigate('RelatedCauses', {
        relatedCauses: causesDic
    })
```

Also, how would I detect the user closing the app, so that I can record the end of a session?